# About uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've read in the Wikipedia about the uncountable set , and I've came into this sentence at the beginning of the article ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set ) : "a set is uncountable if its cardinal number is larger than that of the set of all natural numbers." I didn't understand  how could the cardinal number be larger than that of the set of all natural numbers . It's unclear to me . I'd be happy if someone could help me .

Comment: The set of all subsets of a given set $A$ is called its [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: Do you understand what is the definition of "cardinality" and what does it mean for one set to have a strictly larger cardinality than another?

Comment: @asaf cardinality means the number of elements in a set right ?

Comment: That's the intuitive idea. But for an infinite set, do you know the definitions?

Comment: In set theory, "larger than" is defined rigorously through the "technical" concept of [equinumerosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinumerosity) in such a way to be "applicable" also to infinite sets.

Comment: @Mauro oh okay. But  the set of natural numbers is infinite and we don't know how much is its limit . So how could we analyze the bijectivity of an uncountable set with the set of natural numbers ? For both are infinite . (I'm still new to set theory) .

Comment: @asaf I'm still totally new to these stuff but I'll try to read about them. Is set theory that important to physics ?

Comment: "limit" ? For a set we have no concept of limit (in this context, i.e. regarding cardinality). In set theory, we can define *finite* prior to having defined "numbers":  "a set $A$ is [(Dedekind)-finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) if it is **not** equinumerous with a proper subset $B$ of $A$." "Limit" can mean many things, like e.g. "greatest element": the set of integers less-equal to $0$ is cleraly infinite but has a greatest element: $0$ itself.

Comment: @Mauro thank you . Forgive my misunderstanding . My problem is that when we say that "A set is uncountable if its cardinal number is larger than that of the set of all natural numbers." , we don't know how much elements are there in the uncountable set and the same is for the set of natural numbers because its infinite . I meant by limit , the meaning of finite.

Answer (score 4):

The set of all subsets of a given set $A$ is called the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $\mathcal P(A)$ of $A$.

We can prove that if the set $A$ is finite and has $n$ elements (i.e. the cardinality of $A$ is $n$), then the power set $\mathcal P(A)$ has $2^n$ elements.

[Georg Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor) has proved, with his [diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#General_sets), that "the power set of a set (whether infinite or not) always has strictly higher cardinality than the set itself (informally the power set must be larger than the original set)."

Thus, if $\mathbb N$ (the set of all *natural* numbers) is countable, then the corresponding power set $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ has a cardinality that is strictly greater than that of $\mathbb N$.

> "A set is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) if its cardinal number is larger than that of the set of all natural numbers."

Comment: Thank you @Mauro . But when we say that the cardinal number of a set is larger than the set of all natural numbers , aren't we supposing that the set of all natural numbers is limited ? do we have a limit for it ?